# How to extract data from an html form using django?

Tags: html, django

I have `html form` with some text input for a users registration, the form is like this:

```
<form id="signup-form" action="#" method="post">
                 <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                 <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username" id="name" class="name">

                 <label for="email">Email Adderss</label>
                 <input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="emailAdress" id="email" class="email">
                 
                 <label for="phone">Phone Number - <small>Optional</small></label>
                 <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="phone" id="phone">

            
                 <label for="password">Password</label>
                 <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="pass">
              
                 <label for="passwordCon">Confirm Password</label>
                 <input type="password" name="passwordCon" id="passwordCon" class="passConfirm">
                 <input type="submit" form="signup-form" value="Signup Now" id="submit">
           </form>
```

I want to know, how can i store the values of each input, when the button is submitted and save them in the database, is there a way to call the input field by its ID and store it in Django?

Comment: Can you please share your model and view also?

Comment: Are you using inbuilt `User` model from `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: We need your view, because we don't even know if you are using function or class based view :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code template is missing a lot of things like urls , views and models .
What views you are working with , url of the form submission , and what database. But here is a simple structure of the form submission if you are using django user model and not using custom model .

You have your form template. It works fine , but add a new field after  tag for csrf_verification of the template.

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
...

...
</form>
```

Your urls.py for the signup

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup/" , views.signUpView , name = "user-signup") , 
]
```

Your views.py
I am using a function-based view here and django User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login

def signUpView(request , *args , **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        emailAddress = request.POST.get("emailAddress")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        
        # get all your fields which you gave in the form.

        user = User(userrname = username , email = emailAddress )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        login(request , user)
        return redirect("homepage")
    else :
        return render(request , "signupPage.html")
```

This is your basic template and working of django signup page. And this will do your work which you are asking for. For detailed and specific answer. Elaborate the question.